# Can't open emoji keyboard in Safari

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, input-source

Nowhere in Safari, whether it be in text fields in webpages or in the Safari UI itself (address bar for example), can i show the emoji popup. My keyboard shortcut doesn't reveal it, nor does clicking my input source and "Show Emoji and Symbols" from the menu bar.

How can I fix this and make sure it will always be possible to type emoji directly in Safari? What can I do when this problem happens besides restarting the whole device?

Comment: Does the popup work in other standard applications (e.g. Mail, Pages etc)? Does it still work even when it doesn't work in Safari any longer? Does a Safari restart help? Do you have any system-wide tools which interfere with/capture the keyboard input?

Comment: @nohillside I have Karabiner Elements. It still works everywhere else except Safari. Yes restarting Safari fixes it temporarily.

Comment: If it happens in Safari,  does it also occur in other applications? Do you have any Safari extensions installed? Also, which version of macOS and Safari are you running?

Comment: @nohillside monterey, Safari 15.5, AdGuard and Bitwarden. It doesn't happen in any other apps.

Comment: Can you please do the usual steps to isolate the issue as much as possible? We don‘t have access to your system so we rely on you to do the basic triage.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using M1 mac OS - Monterey.
I use function ( <kbd>fn</kbd> ) key in the bottom left corner of the keyboard to launch emoji keyboard.